# Inject List of Custom Object to map using spring boot configuration properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Getting issue with ConfigurationProperties. I have a configuration like this

```
com:
  test:
    app:
      units:
        unit:
          - query:
              matchType: "sadas"
          - query:
              matchType: "sadas"
```

Wanted to inject this application.yaml to this Map<String,List<Query>>. My Configuration code is like this.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.test.app")
public class UnitsConfiguration {

    private Map<String,List<Query>> units;
//settter, getter
}



public class Query {
    private String matchType;
//settter, getter
}
```

Error I am getting while running this.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@7e357c39 type = java.util.List<Query>, value = 'none', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]]] failed:

    Property: com.test.app.units.unit[0].query.matchtype
    Value: "sadas"
    Origin: class path resource [application.yaml] - 20:26
    Reason: The elements [com.test.app.units.unit[0].query.matchtype,com.test.app.units.unit[1].query.matchtype] were left unbound.
```

Comment: Or you define (+enable!?) `Query` as `@ConfigurationProperties` as well ..or you nest the class (as shown in reference doc)

Comment: It didn't work. Tried to create the nested class. but that also didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your YAML is not defined correctly. Here is working YAML along with Java code

Here is formatted YAML

```
server:
  credentials:
    - list1:
      - key1:
        username: root
        password: rootpass
      - key2:
        username: root
        password: rootpass
    - list2:
      - key21:
        username: root
        password: rootpass
      - key22:
        username: root
        password: rootpass
```

Here is a Java code

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class ServerProperties {

    private Map<String, List<Credential>> credentials = new HashMap<>();
    //getter and setter    

    public static class Credential {

        private String username;
        private String password;

        // Getter/Setter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pkytech, it worked for me. but the keys in the map are like "0.list1" instead of "list1". I tried to further modify it like the below  ** server:
  credentials:
    list1:
      - key1:
        username: root
        password: rootpass
      - key2:
        username: root
        password: rootpass
     list2:
      - key21:
        username: root
        password: rootpass
      - key22:
        username: root
        password: rootpass **  After this change in map i am getting proper key as "list1"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some nested things you need to initalize it and mark them as such. Also add getter/setter to this one:

```
@NestedConfigurationProperty
private final Map<String,List<Query>> units = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. ```Map<String,List<String>>``` worked with or without this annotation. but issue with this custom object

Comment: Do you have getter/setter/ no args constructor on Query object?

Comment: Yes, added the setter getter and no args also. But it didn't work. Seems its not considering map at units level.